# jquery .text() method not getting any text from input type text html element

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I find my element in the DOM like this :

```
tag_text_box = ($(this).parent().parent().find('.tags'))
```

I printed it out to check it is correct and indeed it is.
here:

```
[
<input type=​"text" class=​"tags ui-autocomplete-input" style=​"width:​ 250px;​ height:​ 24px;​ background-color:​ red;​ " name=​"display_name" autocomplete=​"off" role=​"textbox" aria-autocomplete=​"list" aria-haspopup=​"true">​
]
```

However `tag_text_box.text()` seems not to be working at all. It doesn't print whatever text I have typed in my input. Should I use another method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) instead; `.text()` gets the text from *inside* an element, whereas `.val()` gets the value of the text box, which is an *attribute* of the input.

You can also leave the surrounding brackets out in your first line. Note that you should also be using `var`; currently, you're declaring `tag_text_box` in the global namespace. Here's what it should look like:

```
var tag_text_box = $(this).parent().parent().find('.tags');

var box_text = tag_text_box.val();
```

---

To be more concise, you can simply assign the input's value straight to a variable:

```
var tags = $(this).parent().parent().find('.tags').val();
```

Answer (score 2):

To get the value of your text input you'd have to use:

`($(this).parent().parent().find('.tags')).val()`

Answer (score 2):

It is because you should use .val() instead of .text()..

.val() is used for anything where the dom object has a value instead.

You can read more on .val() and which dom elements to use it on here: http://api.jquery.com/val/

Answer (score 1):

`.val()` Grabs the values of inputs.

http://api.jquery.com/val/

Answer (score 1):

use

```
var textboxValue = $(...).val();
```

instead